# I’ve been working on a 2d raycaster that wraps around a sphere, but I can’t seem to find out what’s wrong with my code (P5JS)

Tags: javascript, geometry, p5.js, raycasting

The visualization doesn’t seem to be working. I’ve tried a few things, but I’m not quite sure where the problem is. I’m trying to do raycasting where, instead of casting along a 2d cartesian plane, it’s moving around a 3d sphere (spherical space, non-euclidean geometry). I think it is casting correctly, but I really need some advice on how this needs to be implemented.

EDIT:
I have found out by debugging, that there’s something wrong with my casting algorithm. I’m still not sure what, though.

Note:
I’m still trying to figure out where I went wrong, so the code may change on the link.

```js
var sr = 51;

var DotX = 0;
var DotY = 0;
var DotAngle = 0;

var ax;
var ay;

const T_CUBE = 0; //RGB = 7,8,9
const T_CAM = 1; //1, detect_radius (RGB in vars)
const T_SPHERE = 2; //2, x, y, z, radius, R, G, B (RGB = 5,6,7)

const FOV = 80;
const def = 100;

var things = [
  [1, 1],
  [T_CUBE, -51 / sr, -2 / sr, -2 / sr, 51 / sr, 2 / sr, 2 / sr, 255, 255, 0]
]; //

var Br = 199;
var Bg = 20;
var Bb = 5;

var BUTTON_FORWARD = true;
var BUTTON_BACKWARD = false;
var BUTTON_LEFT = false;
var BUTTON_RIGHT = false;
var BUTTON_TL = false;
var BUTTON_TR = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key == "W") {
    BUTTON_FORWARD = true;
  } else if (key == "S") {
    BUTTON_BACKWARD = true;
  } else if (key == "A") {
    BUTTON_LEFT = true;
  } else if (key == "D") {
    BUTTON_RIGHT = true;
  } else if (key == ",") {
    BUTTON_TL = true;
  } else if (key == ".") {
    BUTTON_TR = true;
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (key == "W") {
    BUTTON_FORWARD = false;
  } else if (key == "S") {
    BUTTON_BACKWARD = false;
  } else if (key == "A") {
    BUTTON_LEFT = false;
  } else if (key == "D") {
    BUTTON_RIGHT = false;
  } else if (key == ",") {
    BUTTON_TL = false;
  } else if (key == ".") {
    BUTTON_TR = false;
  }
}

/*function gwhdb(l){
  return abs(l[4]*sr-l[1]*sr),abs(l[5]*sr-l[2]*sr),abs(l[6]*sr-l[3]*sr);
}*/

function draw() {
  noStroke();
  background(0);
  shininess(20);
  ambientLight(50);
  specularColor(255, 0, 0);
  pointLight(255, 0, 0, 0, -50, 50);
  specularColor(0, 255, 0);
  pointLight(0, 255, 0, 0, 50, 50);
  specularMaterial(255);
  //sphere(sr);
  //fill(255,255,0);
  //box(gwhdb(things[1]));
  //box(100,4,4);

  ax = cos(DotAngle);
  ay = sin(DotAngle);
  if (BUTTON_FORWARD == true) {
    DotX += 0.05 * ax;
    DotY += 0.05 * ay;
  }
  if (BUTTON_BACKWARD == true) {
    DotX -= 0.05 * ax;
    DotY -= 0.05 * ay;
  }
  if (BUTTON_LEFT == true) {
    DotX -= 0.05 * ay;
    DotY -= 0.05 * ax;
  }
  if (BUTTON_RIGHT == true) {
    DotX += 0.05 * ay;
    DotY += 0.05 * ax;
  }
  if (BUTTON_TL) {
    DotAngle += 0.1;
  }
  if (BUTTON_TR) {
    DotAngle -= 0.1;
  }

  push();
  //lon,x lat,y
  var a = sr * cos(DotY) * cos(DotX);
  var b = sr * cos(DotY) * sin(DotX);
  var c = sr * sin(DotY);
  translate(a, b, c);
  color(255);
  sphere(3);
  pop();
  var info = castAround(DotX, DotY, FOV, def, DotAngle, a, b, c);
  //console.log(info);

  render(info);
}

function render(INFO) {
  //console.log(INFO);
  for (i = 0; i < INFO.length; i++) {
    //console.log(INFO[i]);
    fill(getColor(INFO[i][1], INFO[i][0]));
    var RH = sr - INFO[i][0];
    rect(1 / INFO.length * i * width - (width / 2), height / 2 - (RH / 2) - (height / 2), 1 / INFO.length * width, RH);
  }
  //rectMode(CORNER);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  //rect(1/3*width-(width/2),150-(height/2),133.33,100);
  //rect(1/3*width-(width/2),250-(height/2),133.33,100);
}

function getColor(object, info_i) {
  var a = things[object][0];
  if (a == T_CAM) {
    return [Br, Bg, Bb];
  } else if (a == T_CUBE) {
    return [things[object][7] - info_i, things[object][8] - info_i, things[object][9] - info_i];
  } else if (a == T_SPHERE) {
    return [things[object][5], things[object][6], things[object][7]];
  } else {
    return [0, 255, 0];
  }
}

function castAround(spx, spy, fov, ra, san, a, b, c) {
  //do a loop for every ra
  var can = san - (fov * 0.5);

  var INFORMATION = [];
  //console.log("INFORMATION set");
  for (var i = 0; i < ra; i++) {
    //while loop to an object
    //console.log("for ra");
    var running = true;
    var rx = spx;
    var ry = spy;
    var rvx = cos(can);
    var rvy = sin(can);
    var dist = 0;

    while (running) {
      //console.log("while running");
      rx += rvx;
      ry += rvy;
      dist++;

      var cx = sr * cos(ry) * cos(rx);
      var cy = sr * cos(ry) * sin(rx);
      var cz = sr * sin(ry);
      for (var j = 0; j < things.length; j++) {
        if (things[j][0] == T_CUBE) {
          //T_CUBE, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, r, g, b
          if (cx > things[j][1] * sr && cx < things[j][4] * sr && cy > things[j][2] * sr && cy < things[j][5] * sr && cz > things[j][3] * sr && cz < things[j][6] * sr) {
            running = false;
            INFORMATION.push([dist, j]);
          }
        }
        if (things[j][0] == T_CAM) {

          if (pDist3(cx, cy, cz, a, b, c) - things[j][1] <= 0 && dist > things[j][1]) {
            running = false;
            INFORMATION.push([dist, j]);
            //console.log(dist);

            push();
            translate(cx, cy, cz);
            fill(255, 255, 0);
            sphere(5);
            pop();
          }

        }


      }
    }
    can += (fov / ra);
  }
  return INFORMATION;
}

function pDist(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2));
}

function pDist3(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) {
  return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)) + ((z2 - z1) * (z2 - z1)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

You can also run it at https://editor.p5js.org/hpestock/sketches/qtolHtr3H

Comment: The code in this post behaves differently than the code at the link. Also it's pretty unclear what the expected behavior is.

Comment: I'm guessing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870259/how-would-i-go-about-writing-a-program-to-rotate-at-point-around-a-sphere-based was a follow up on this one? Is this still relevant? If not you should delete it.

Comment: The other one is a separate project doing a similar thing, but I think this one has a few different problems than the other one. I've been trying to change around stuff in the code in the link, so the code on this post is different in some places.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the issue is specifically the way the sphere moves when the user presses the different keys? And that you want it to move similarly to in the other question (i.e. in a circular orbit around the center)? Because if so then I feel like the same code will work.

Comment: I need to be able to set a specific angle and move a ray in that direction, as similar to the other question, but I also think something else is wrong here as well. (Not sure what, though)